# Create map series using ArcPy in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

We can create a map series using the "Map Series" button. So, can we use ArcPy to automate the manual process?

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/mapseries-class.htm

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a note at the top of the [mapseries-class](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/mapseries-class.htm) page that you linked to that states:

> You cannot use arcpy.mp to create a map series.

However you can create a new spatial map series via the CIM object.

There is an example called MapSeries_CreateNew.py that is provided in the [ArcGIS Pro 2.5 CIM Samples V1](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=8772f61319584882bb697ba003030636) that you can find on https://codesharing.arcgis.com/